# How can I get just the timezone out of this?

Tags: php, api

I am trying to get the timezone out of that in php.

```
a:14:{s:3:"zip";s:5:"78229";s:3:"lon";d:-98.5746990000;s:6:"status";s:7:"success";s:5:"query";s:13:"72.***.***.**";s:3:"org";s:17:"Time Warner Cable";s:2:"as";s:38:"AS11427 Time Warner Cable Internet LLC";s:4:"city";s:11:"San Antonio";s:8:"timezone";s:15:"America/Chicago";s:7:"country";s:13:"United States";s:3:"isp";s:17:"Time Warner Cable";s:10:"regionName";s:5:"Texas";s:3:"lat";d:29.50700000;s:11:"countryCode";s:2:"US";s:6:"region";s:2:"TX";}
```

Here is the link I am using http://ip-api.com/php/[YOUR_IP_HERE]

Comment: how about json_decode ?

Comment: Got it... Had to change php to json in the url lol

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation, [Link to Docs](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php)

It looks like what you have is serialized PHP.  You can decode that online:

[Deserializer for PHP](http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/)

and with PHP functions, although as it says, you are probably better off using JSON, e.g. http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8 and processing that.   You could use PHP or something like jQuery to parse the string.

I don't use jsfiddle much, but you could see if this works and makes sense.  I should note that when I am signed into jsfiddle the protocol is https and the code doesn't work because the protocol for the JSON is http.  It should work with the link provided though.

```
JS

$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8", function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
  });
        items.push("<li>The Time Zone is just data.timezone:  "+data.timezone+"</li>")
  $("<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join("")
  }).appendTo("#results");
});

HTML

<div id="results"></div>
```

[jQuery.getJSON Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sscotti/0q6dg8cd/)

If you just want to use PHP without jQuery you can try something like:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
echo $obj->timezone;
echo "</pre>";
?>
```